# c# how assign static class to instance variable?

Tags: c#, static, instance

Static members can't be called with instance, like `instance.myStaticProperty`.

Is there any way, that I can have an instance variable that will be an alias of static self class? like:

```
class myClass
{
    public string a ="hello";
    public static string b ="world";

    public myClass myVariable = global::myClass;   // <--- phseudo code
}
```

and i could call:

```
myClass instance= new myClass();
instance.myVariable.b; //
```

Comment: My question to you would be: If they are static, why would you _want to_ call them on an instance? What is the usecase?

Comment: btw, I guess it's a typo: duplicate "static" on `b` ...

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This seems like it could get very confusing.

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't let this past review even if it were possible. As Sweeper sais, it is really confusing. User will expect an instance field and the according behavior but actually get the behavior of a static field. Bad idea.

Comment: Guys, i won't just answer you. I am tired of comments "why you want that". You can ignore this topic too.

Comment: @T.Todua I am learning every day. Maybe you have a legit usecase? If you do not want to explain, that's up to you, of course. I didn't ask to annoy you. I was wondering if I could provide a better alternative if I knew what problem it is, you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. The closest you get is using a `using`.

Your static class definition:

```
class ClassA
{
    public static string A = "A";
}
```

And to use it:

```
using StaticClassA = ConsoleApp1.ClassA;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = StaticClassA.A;
    }
}
```

Not too much to gain though, but it might ease your naming a little.

Another (somewhat cooler) option is a `static using`:

```
using static ConsoleApp1.StaticClassA;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = A;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I want a class **which contains instance methods and static methods** too."_ (emphasis by me) So I think a static class won't do.

Comment: @Fildor Uhm, no. Indeed. You can remove the `static` safely btw.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to do an anti-pattern there.

Static properties are properties not defined in an instance (object) of that class, but by the class itself. And as such, you can access and modify them whenever you choose to, provided you have the required scopes to do so.

I don't see the problem in calling `MyClass.StaticProperty = <some expression>`, if indeed the functions the static property do, are static. If it's something part of the object, something you don't connect with the class itself, i.e it might be different for each instanced object of that class, then just turn it into a regular property instead.

Example of some static properties and methods:

```
public class DoMath
{
   public static string Pi { get; private set; } = "3.14";
   public static double X {get; set;}
   public static double Y {get; set;}

   public static double Sum() => X + Y;
}

DoMath.X = 3.5;
DoMath.Y = 4;
double result = DoMath.Sum();
Console.WriteLine($"Pi is equal to {DoMath.Pi}.");
```

If you truly wish something to be static, then don't try to make it non-static. Simply declare it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Static members are shared across all instances of the class or all instances of Class Of T of same T.

So you can access static properties outside of class by using the `ClassName.VarName` or directly by the `VarName` from within the class.

You can access static fields and properties and methods from all non static methods.

You can also add an instance member mapping a static member.

Instances of a static thing can't exist in addition to the static existence itself.

So you can write this:

```
class myClass
{
  public string a = "hello";

  static public string b = "world";

  public string B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    b = "new world";
  }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
myClass instance= new myClass();
instance.DoSomething();
myClass.b = "another world";
instance.B = "C# world";
```